# Using complex where clause in NHibernate mapping layer

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I've used where clauses previously in the mapping layer to prevent certain records from ever getting into my application at the lowest level possible. (Mainly to prevent having to re-write lots of lines of code to filter out the unwanted records)

These have been simple, one column queries, like so

`this.Where("Invisible = 0");`

However a scenario has appeared which requires the use of an `exists` sql query.

`exists (select ep_.Id from [Warehouse].[dbo].EventPart ep_ where Id = ep_.EventId and ep_.DataType = 4`

In the above case I would usually reference the parent table `Event` with a short name, i.e. `event_.Id` however as Nhibernate generates these short names dynamically it's impossible to know what it's going to be.

So instead I tried using just `Id`, from above `ep_ where Id = ep_.EventId`

When the code is run, because of the dynamic short names the EventPart table short name `ep_` is has another short name prefixed to it, `event0_.ep_` where `event0_` refers to the parent table.

This causes an SQL error because of the . in between `event0_` and `ep_`

So in my `EventMap` I have the following

`this.Where("(exists (select ep_.Id from [isnapshot.Warehouse].[dbo].EventPart ep_ where Id = ep_.EventId and ep_.DataType = 4)");`

but when it's generated it creates this

`select cast(count(*) as INT) as col_0_0_

from [isnapshot.Warehouse].[dbo].Event event0_

where (exists (select ep_.Id from [isnapshot.Warehouse].[dbo].EventPart event0_.ep_ where event0_.Id = ep_.EventId and ep_.DataType = 4)`

It has correctly added the `event0_` to the `Id`

Was the mapping layer where clause built to handle this and if so where am I going wrong?

Comment: Which NHibernate version is this?

Comment: @Oskar Currently using 3.3.1.4000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting square brackets around the alias like this:

```
exists (select ep_.Id from [Warehouse].[dbo].EventPart [ep_] where Id = ep_.EventId and ep_.DataType = 4
```

Comment: Wow, that's surprisingly simple.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "as" keyword when defining the ep_ alias.

Comment: Same problem unfortunately. It still adds the event0_ to the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

The NHibernate.SqlCommand.Template class has a method (RenderWhereStringTemplate) that modifies the Where clause.  Looking at the code, I think the problem comes in that it thinks that ep_ is an identifier (basically a property of the mapped class) so it prefixes it with the table's prefix.  The code to determine whether it's an identifier or not is quite simple - it basically checks if it's quoted, or if it starts with a-z and doesn't contain .

I think the simplest solution is to change your alias from ep_ to _ep - I typically use 2 _'s to make sure it doesn't conflict with a prefix that NHibernate generates.